# 'ffi' package not found in iTorch

Tags: shell, lua, ffi, torch

when I run itorch command, I see the following output:

```
 Torch 7.0  Copyright (C) 2001-2011 Idiap, NEC Labs, NYU
 /usr/local/bin/lua: /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/itorch/IOHandler.lua:17: module 'ffi' not found:
 no field package.preload['ffi']
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/ffi.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/ffi/init.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ffi.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ffi/init.lua'
 no file './ffi.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/ffi.so'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
 no file './ffi.so'
stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'require'
 /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/itorch/IOHandler.lua:17: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'require'
 (command line):1: in main chunk
 [C]: in ?
Jupyter Console 4.1.1

ERROR: Kernel did not respond

Shutting down kernel
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `ffi` via luarocks.

`luarocks install torchffi`

Comment: I had to exec `luarocks install --server=https://luarocks.org/dev luaffi` to install it, luarocks didn't found torchffi.